# Disable button behavior depending on confirmation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Im using Handsontable, and I need to display a confirmation message when the delete row button is pressed (I'm using the RemoveRow plugin http://handsontable.com/demo/buttons.html).

The thing is that depending on the confirmation message I have to prevent the row from being deleted if the user selects 'No', and I cant find a way to cancel the deletion event.

The plugin delete button is a div with class 'btn'. There is one of this buttons for each row on the grid.
The event/function I need must be bound to these buttons and prevent the 'mouseup' event from triggering if the confirmation returns false.

Summarizing, I need to disable the deletion event if the user made a mistake pressing the button. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [`if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) delete_this_row();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm)

Answer (score 0):

`confirm()` returns `true` is yes is clicked and `false` if no

So you can do something like

```
if (confirm("Do you want to delete row"))
 {
 // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')"
```